# django production server - Django not sending mail in 500 error case to ADMINS

Tags: python, django, apache2, settings, mod-wsgi

i have deployed django project finally on server and now it is working, but once i go to `/admin/`, i am getting 500 page but not notification.

this is what i have in settings_prod.py

```
from settings import *
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False    
SERVER_EMAIL='my_mail@mail.com'    
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='my_mail@mail.com'    
ADMINS = (
    (u'me', 'my_mail@mail.com'),
)    
MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

what am i doing wrong?

Do i need any SMTP setups for this? i thought, this is server mailing, so server has already everything setup to send error mails.

Comment: When in doubt, check the server's error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it by installing `sendmail` on server. for those who encounters the same problem.

```
apt-get install sendmail
```

I am in Debian.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

In the official Django documentation I quickly found the solution for my environment, Apache 2.2.22 (Debian) and Django 1.9:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#console-backend

Comment: You must quote the relevant answer from the documentation.

Comment: Everything depends on the email backend you need in your project, hence a response so incoherent.
In my case, I needed to use **SMTP** mail I included the following line in settings.py:
**EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'**
Thanks for comment.