# Django does not send messages about 500 errors

Tags: python, django, email

Okay. So I am really not happy with that I am probably posting another duplicate question, but nothing relevant seems to help me.

So the problem is that I want to receive emails containing server error messages (500), and I don't.

What do I know:

1. Everything works just fine on my local machine: I get my messages when I set `DEBUG = False`. Too many of them, being honest.
2. Calling `django.core.mail.mail_admins()` from within `./manage.py shell` on production server is working fine: I get my emails, as I get those that are sent by `send_email()` from within a view
3. I have `DEBUG = False` set on my production server
4. I am trying to get email by messing up my home template with missing parentheses and also by putting `assert 0` string into my home view. I am getting my 500.html rendered alright with that.
5. Here are my email settings in settings.py:

   ```
   EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@<project-name>.ru'
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<password>'
   EMAIL_PORT = 587
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@<project-name>.ru'
   SERVER_EMAIL = 'noreply@<project-name>.ru'
   ```

   Here are my logging settings in settings.py:

   ```
   LOGGING = {
       'version': 1,
       'disable_existing_loggers': False,
       'filters': {
           'require_debug_false': {
               '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
           }
       },
       'handlers': {
           'mail_admins': {
               'level': 'ERROR',
               'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
               'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
           }
       },
       'loggers': {
           'django': {
               'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
               'level': 'ERROR',
               'propagate': False,
           },
       }
   }
   ```

   I also tried changing 'propagate' to True, but didn't succeed

   And here is my ADMINS from settings.py:
   `ADMINS = (('xelnod', 'xelnod@gmail.com'),)`

   I am using Django 1.7 with Python 2.7.6

   And the production server is running on '57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux'

   I was here: 
   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414130/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414130/django-not-sending-emails-to-admins),
   and here:
   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374909/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374909/django-error-email-report-not-being-sent),
   and even here:
   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634962/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634962/django-production-server-django-not-sending-mail-in-500-error-case-to-admins) (so I did run `sudo apt-get install sendmail` already),
   and in some [other](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/9VE2FhN1dBw) [places](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/internal-server-error-not-sending-message-notification-td5016031.html) — unfortunately, no luck with that.

…am I missing something (I bet it would be something very stupid…)?

**UPD:** I noticed that I only receive email messages concerning my static files when I test this on my local — nothing about broken template or AssertionError, so, I guess, it must be something with my error level or my 500 errors are not bad enough for Django to email them… Tried setting handler and logger levels to INFO, but nothing changed

Comment: try change `loggers` => `'level': 'DEBUG'`

Answer (score 0):

what's the error message when you have `DEBUG = True`?

And maybe you need to fix your 500 template, because if that one is broken, you cannot see a 500 error page of a 500 error page

Comment: `AssertionError at /

No exception message supplied

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8082/
Django Version:  1.7c2
Exception Type:  AssertionError`

That's the one on the home page.

Comment: Well, I see my 500.html template, doesn't it mean that there are no errors there?

Comment: Are there any templatetags in your 500.html? Try removing them first and just use plain text (nothing else) in this template.
Otherwise, post the complete stacktrace for further investigation

Comment: Sorry for delay! Tried removing all templatetags - no success. Here's the stacktrace... `AssertionError at /

No exception message supplied

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8082/
Django Version:  1.7
Exception Type:  AssertionError
Exception Location:  /home/ubuntu/repos/tenderon/tenderon/views.py in home, line 164
Python Executable:  /venv/tenderon/bin/python
Python Version:  2.7.6
Python Path:  

['some paths here']` sorry, had to cut out the PYTHONPATH for my comment not to be too long. Can't see anything interesting in the trace, though :(

Comment: It does say something about your view `/home/ubuntu/repos/tenderon/tenderon/views.py in home, line 164` maybe you should check that line?

Comment: That line just says "assert 0". I deliberately wrote that one in order to get 500 error and receive an email about that since my project usually doesn't throw these...